# Visual Studio Code `jsconfig.json` "module" option

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I'm using [jsconfig.json](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/archive/2015/07/06/vs-code-es6.aspx) to configure Visual Studio code to enable ES6 support in my project. In the `compilerOptions` node of the config file there is an option called "module" that takes one of four possible values:

1. `commonjs`
2. `amd`
3. `system`
4. `umd`

I understand that `commonjs`, `amd` and `umd` are JS module systems.

My question is what is the `system` value? It sounds like a "default, inherit the setting from elsewhere" type of setting but I cannot find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ES6's `System` module loader, which was removed in 2014.

Here's an example of how it looks like:
https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader

Comment: So not the ES6 [`import statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) correct?

Comment: Yeah, it's something like `System.module('name', ['deps'], function() {})` I think.